# jaxb2:xjc Two declarations cause a collision in the ObjectFactory class. when using type extension in XSD

Tags: java, jaxb, xjc

I've schema with a lot of complex types with extensions as follows:

```
 <xs:complexType name="GenericFieldValue">
    <xs:choice>
        <xs:element name="String" nillable="true">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:simpleContent>
                    <xs:extension base="xs:string"/>
                </xs:simpleContent>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
    </xs:choice>
</xs:complexType>

 <xs:element name="Value">
    <xs:complexType>
     <xs:complexContent>
       <xs:extension base="aip:GenericFieldValue">
         <xs:attribute name="Type" type="aip:GenericDataFieldType" use="required"/>
       </xs:extension>
     </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
 </xs:element>
```

Maven plugin as follows:

```
            <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>xjc</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>xjc</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/java/schema</outputDirectory>
                <sources>
                    <source>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/schema/SITA_AIP_Message.xsd</source>
                </sources>
                <externalEntityProcessing>true</externalEntityProcessing>
                <clearOutputDir>false</clearOutputDir>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

I'm getting this compilation error
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1B9PF.png)

I've read all available answers but nothing helped me know how should I fix this error?